# Replace on FeynCalc

Tags: replacement, feyncalc

I can do replacements easily using /.

```
p = {1, 2, 3}; //in
input = 4 Overscript[p, _]^2 /. {Overscript[x_, _]^2 -> x.x} //in
56 //Out
```

However, using the same expression on a FeynCalc output, it doesn't do anything:

```
<<Feyncalc`
DiracTrace[GS[p] GS[p], DiracTraceEvaluate -> True] /. {Overscript[x_, _]^2 -> x.x} //In
4 Overscript[{1,2,3}, _]^2 // Out
```

How can I get the desired result from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do it. Using //Standardform to obtain an expression like:
    4 Pair[Momentum[{4, 2, 3, 1}], Momentum[{4, 2, 3, 1}]]

I can then use:

```
p = {4, 2, 3, 1};
g = DiagonalMatrix [{1, -1, -1, -1}];
<<FeynCalc`
output = DiracTrace[GS[p] GS[p], DiracTraceEvaluate -> True] // StandardForm ;
output /. { Pair[Momentum[x_], Momentum[y_]] -> x.g.y}
8 // [Out]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but after hours of going through the Feyncalc source code I figured out that it can be done simply by declaring that

```
$TypesettingDim4 = ""
```

inside your document. Hope this saves someone a bunch of time some time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "." operator for non-commutative input, i.e., it really should be `GS[p].GS[p]`, and not `GS[p]*GS[p]`.

Resetting `$PrePrint` and setting `$Post` to `FeynCalcExternal` (`FCE` for short)
provides an alternative to see what is going on:

```
In[2]:= $PrePrint
      
Out[2]= FeynCalcForm
    
In[3]:= $PrePrint=.; $Post = FCE;
    
In[4]:=  t = FCE @ TR @ (GS[p] . GS[p])
    
Out[4]= 4 SP[p, p]

In[5]:= t /. SP[x_, x_] :> x.x

Out[5]= 4 p . p

In[6]:= %//InputForm

Out[6]//InputForm= 4*p . p
```